# How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

The website in the iframe **isn't located in the same domain**, but both are mine, and I would like to communicate between the `iframe` and the parent site. Is it possible?

Answer (score 495, accepted):

With different domains, it is not possible to call methods or access the iframe's content document directly.

You have to use [cross-document messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

### parent -> iframe

For example in the top window:

```js
myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
```

and in the iframe:

```js
window.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (e.data == 'hello') {
        alert('It works!');
    }
};
```

### iframe -> parent

For example in the top window:

```js
window.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (e.data == 'hello') {
        alert('It works!');
    }
};
```

and in the iframe:

```js
window.top.postMessage('hello', '*')
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't works in older browsers.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 : Can you put a simple example?

Comment: In the parent: `window.onmesage = function()...`. In the iframe: `window.top.postMessage('hello', '*')`

Comment: @Pumbaa80 when I do that, I get two errors in the chrome console, but still, it works. `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///iframe.html from frame with URL file:///parent.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: @Zelenova That may be due to a bug in Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94618

Comment: It's not a bug. File urls can be very unsafe and browsers are treating them with ever increasing care. Back in the old days you could put a link to `file://C:/Windows/system32/whatever` on a webpage and make it point right into the user's system folder. These days browsers mostly ignore clicks on links like that. Run a webserver and access your code through that and you'll see the errors diappear.

Comment: Can you provide a demo please. @Pumbaa80

Comment: As a good practice, never use the '*' for your target. In fact, MDN says - "Always provide a specific targetOrigin, not *, if you know where the other window's document should be located. Failing to provide a specific target discloses the data you send to any interested malicious site."

Comment: We can even use `window.frames[index]` to get child frame (`<iframe>, <object>, <frame>`), equivalent to `getElementsByTagName("iframe")[index].contentWindow`. To get Parent Window Object from IFrames, it is better to use `window.parent`, as `window.top` represents the Top Most Parent Window

Comment: I've done same thing for VSCode, see my blog post https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-pass-data-between-iframe-and-parent-window/

Comment: As of this writing, March of 2021, cross-browser support for `window.onmessage` is not complete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onmessage#browser_compatibility

Comment: @user123444555621 hey that's onmessage not onmesage :) I copy-and-paste and it does not work then i see this bug

Answer (score 106):

In 2018 and modern browsers you can send a custom event from iframe to parent window.

iframe:

```js
var data = { foo: 'bar' }
var event = new CustomEvent('myCustomEvent', { detail: data })
window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event)
```

parent:

```js
window.document.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', handleEvent, false)
function handleEvent(e) {
  console.log(e.detail) // outputs: {foo: 'bar'}
}
```

PS: Of course, you can send events in opposite direction same way.

```js
document.querySelector('#iframe_id').contentDocument.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Comment: Hello, do I have to be on the same domain to do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: It should be noted that `dispatchEvent` is supported in all major browsers. IE9 was the first version it came in, so most OSs now work with it.
https://caniuse.com/#search=dispatchEvent

Comment: I am not able to communicate from parent to iframe with this method.

Comment: Yeah I can't get it to work either, the iframe js is loading after the parent window so it is not there to receive the msg when sent. it only works from iframe to parent for me.

Comment: There is a simple solution to that Avan and @radtek. All you have to do is first dispatch an event from the iframe to the parent that notifies the parent that the iframe is loaded (essentially a "ready message"). The parent will be listening for messages and if it receives the "ready message" event, it can then reply to the iframe with whatever message you want to send. That way it sends the message to the iframe only once the iframe is loaded. And of course the iframe page will only send the message to the parent once it is loaded.

Comment: Already figured it out sometime ago, made a prototype repo - https://github.com/radzhome/django_sso_service

Comment: I tested it and it works only for same origin frames. Cross-origin will result in a `SecurityError` when accessing `window.parent`

Comment: Make sure when you set the iframe to add the following for this to work: `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="..."></iframe>`

Comment: Does dispatchEvent better then postMessage? From the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183600/difference-between-custom-event-and-postmessage postMessage is safer and support cross-domains

Answer (score 15):

This library supports HTML5 postMessage and legacy browsers with resize+hash https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole

Edit: Now in 2014, IE6/7 usage is quite low, IE8 and above all support `postMessage` so I now suggest to just use that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: With the caveat that IE8/9 only support strings http://caniuse.com/#search=postmessage (See known issues)

Comment: this can be worked around by encoding your event objects to json and decode them on the other side.

Answer (score 12):

Use `event.source.window.postMessage` to send back to sender.

From Iframe

```
window.top.postMessage('I am Iframe', '*')
window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data === 'GOT_YOU_IFRAME') {
        console.log('Parent received successfully.')
    }
}
```

Then from parent say back.

```
window.onmessage = (event) => {
    event.source.window.postMessage('GOT_YOU_IFRAME', '*')
}
```

#### Updated:

`postMessage` should not work on cross domain, so the solution like this:

For example your website is: `customer.com` and your domain is `my.com`

You need to do like this

- Create a js file (upload to CDN or your server) - `my.com`
- Embed js file above to `customer.com`

Now from `my.com`, you can `postMessage` and above embed script can be received data from you.

Comment: As of this writing, March of 2021, cross-browser support for `window.onmessage` is not complete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onmessage#browser_compatibility

Comment: @flyingace The only caveat I'm aware of is cross-domain iframe messaging on IE. Are you aware of any gaps between modern browsers?

Comment: For cross-browser or crossing domain, you can embed a script with the same domain to website and postMessage it as normal. Cross domain will not work. So embed script is a solution, not a workaround.

Comment: THANKYOU!! lost so much hair over this. The only solution that actually worked

Answer (score 2):

the `window.top` property should be able to give what you need.

E.g.

```
alert(top.location.href)
```

See 
http://cross-browser.com/talk/inter-frame_comm.html

Comment: As the iframe isn't on the same domain he can't access its parent.

Answer (score 2):

After spending 2 days trying to get an iFrame posting messages back to the parent, a Vue application in my situation, I came across this excellent reference:

https://dev-bay.com/iframe-and-parent-window-postmessage-communication/

From the iframe to parent:

```
    const parentWindow = window.parent;
    class Message {
        constructor(type, body) {
          this.type = type;
          this.body = body;
        }
    };

    function sendMessage (windowObj, payload) {
        if(windowObj) {
          windowObj.postMessage(payload, "*");
        }
    };

    //Then call appropriately: 
    sendMessage(parentWindow, new Message("button-click", "Show Stats Overlay"));
```

In the parent, my Vue application mounted life cycle event, but reference the link for your own requirement:

```
    window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
        var data = e.data;
        console.log("RECEIVED message from CHILD TO PARENT", data);
        
        var type = data.type;
        var body = data.body;

        if(type === "button-click" && body) {
          console.log("button-click RECEIVED FROM CHILD")
          //Additional functionality ...
        } else if (type === "text-msg" && body) {
          console.log("TEXT MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM CHILD");
          //Additional functionality ...
        }
      });
```

Please see reference for examples of communication from Parent to iFrame.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`postMessage(message, '*')`;

Comment: not too informative, I've tried to descrive the process in my blog post https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-pass-data-between-iframe-and-parent-window/