# When working with iFrames is it possible to pass data to an iframe first and then have the iframe load a page based on data passed to it?

Tags: php, jquery, post, iframe, communication

Basically I have this PHP page (call it the parent frame or container) and it will receive `$_POST` data from another website. However, within the parent frame or container page I need to have an iframe loading a page containing a form. However, I would like to be able to pass the `$_POST` data to the page specified within the iframe **before the iframe page loads** so that it can load content based on the `$_POST` data passed to it from the parent frame.

Is this possible and if so, is it possible also in Internet Explorer browsers 9 and 10? I ask about IE because I'm used to the fact that most things just work on Firefox and Chrome and those are the three browsers that my client cares about supporting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be acceptable to pass the POST data to the iframe via GET?  If so, you could load the iframe with:

```
src="iframe.php?data=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['data']) ?>"
```

Comment: Always use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to properly encode query string variables and variable names.

Comment: I think you're thinking of urlencode(), but point taken...   http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Indeed, I thought it was JavaScript in your example, not PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just use GET variables

Send post data to your iframe:

```
<iframe src="form.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['yourdata']); ?>" />.
```

In your form.php you can retrieve the value of `var` using `$_GET['var']`:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['var']); //will output *yourdata* ?>
```

Comment: Always use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to properly encode query string variables and variable names.

Comment: Oh, and when `echo`'ing content to a web page, always use `htmlspecialchars`, otherwise the site is prone to XSS.

Comment: This was just an example, I don't worry too much about XSS since that is the job of OP. Thanks for the tip tho :)

Comment: You *should* worry about XSS. I know this is just an example, but an insecure example is a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

Since google always brings this post up, and there's a way to do it discreetly without URLs:

In your index.php call `session_start();` at the very top of the page.
Also do this in the page you're invoking via the iframe, e.g. `iframe.php`

Now both pages have access to the superglobal `$_SESSION[""];`

If on index.php you set `$_SESSION["space"] = " World"` then invoke the iframe.php, in iframe.php you can do `echo 'hello ' . $_SESSION["space"];`

And that should have it output: Hello World