# How to respond to ajax call from iframe?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

Inside my iframe page, user can add or delete items from a list by ajax calls.

I need to also update the number of items in the list in my parent page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done communication between a parent and an iFrame using Javascript in the iFrame to post the message to the parent.

In the iFrame:

```
window.top.postMessage('Message', '*');
```

You can also post this message server side (C#) by calling (*Note that you will need a asp:ScriptManager control on the page to do this)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "login_message", "javascript:window.top.postMessage('Message', '*');", true);
```

In the Parent, you will need to setup a listener:

```
/* Retrieve message from iFrame */
window.onmessage = function (e) {
    var strMessage = e.data.toString();
    if (strMessage == 'Message') {
        /* Message Actions */
    }
};
```

If you have compatibility issues with IE 7 or 10+, you may need to handle it this way.  I found that the way I was doing it above had issues in certain versions of IE (even certain newer ones, like 10).

```
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
    var strMessage = e.data.toString();
    if (strMessage == 'Message') {
        /* Message Actions */
    }
}, false);
```

In this example, the string "Message" is being passed from the iFrame to the parent.  The parent stores it in the var strMessage upon receiving it.  I then check that the message is what I expect before applying actions.  You could easily make the message the number of items in your list.

This is very similar to [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)  Note that this will not work in IE 7 or older.