# How to access outer element of iframe tag from inner element of iframe tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

```
<div id="fancybox-content" style="height:200px;">
    <iframe id="fancybox-frame">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <div class="inner-div"><p class="click-here">Button</p></div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>   
</div>
```

Initially height of div#fancybox-content is 200px but on click of button, height of div.inner-div is increases.
so I want to increase the height of div#fancybox-content also.

So how do I achieve using Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Is the IFrame in the same domain as your outer page? If not you have to do this using message posting.

Eg in the outer window:

```
myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
```

and in the iframe:

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
    if (e.data == 'hello') {
        alert('It works!');
    }
}
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Comment: both are in same domain.