# Firefox localstorage from iframge - SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have 2 subdomains:

- www.example.com = For logged in users only
- internal.example.com = Public website

Since I use localstorage to store some informations on internal.example.com which I need on www.example.com I had implemented the following solution:

I load on www an iframe located on internal. I set on both sides the document domain value to the "parent domain"

```
document.domain = "example.com";
```

Now on www, I can access the localStorage of internal over www by doing the following:

```
frames['internalFrameName'].window.localStorage;
```

Now I can read and write values. This works in Chrome and Internetexplorer, and it worked in Firefox until the last update to FF30. Now I get the error:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a messaging system to communicate between the both frames. Then the iframe can just send you the local storage data.

This might help you with that: [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

You need to use frames['internalFrameName'].postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);

Answer (score 1):

Gecko throws the error message when cookies are disabled so besides the object detection for `localStorage` (which I'm sure you're doing in the code you didn't post) *first* check for support for cookies.

Change:

```
if (window.localStorage)
```

To:

```
if (document.cookie && window.localStorage)
```