# Load iframe before other content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe loading on my page. The content of the iframe only loads after the rest of the content has loaded on the page. Is it possible to load the content within the iframe before the rest of the content on the main page?

Thanks

Comment: where's the content of the iframe coming from?

Comment: Its coming from a sub domain. The main domain is a wordpress site and its pulling in a form from a website on a sub domain

Comment: Could you try and post something on jsfiddle?

Comment: you can have display:none in your parent page except the iframe and when iframe finishes loading you need to communicate with parent page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site) and reveal parent site content by removing display:none

Comment: Isn't there a way of forcing the iframe to load first with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <iframe id="miiframe" src="http://www.apple.com"></iframe>
    <!-- example -->
    <div id="loading" style="position:fixed;background:red;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;"></div>
    <img id="background" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;"/>

<script>
var loaded = false;
console.log(loaded);
function preloader(){
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("miiframe").style.display = "block";
    loaded = true;
            console.log(loaded);
}//preloader
var loadiframe = document.getElementById('miiframe');
loadiframe.onload = preloader;

if(!loaded){
    window.onload = function(){
        background = document.getElementById("background");
        background.src ="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/cute_baby_in_autumn-wide.jpg";
    };
}
</script>
```

<kbd>[see JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1k6atmL5/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// hold `ready` event
$.holdReady(true);

var frame = $("<iframe>");

$(frame).load(function(e) {
    // release `ready` event
    $.holdReady(false)
});

// append `frame` to document
$("body").append(frame);

$(document).ready(function() {
  // do stuff 
  // after `frame` loaded
  $("body").append("done")
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/x7ptnbjy/

See [jQuery.holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/)