# Call function on object trhough jquery selector from iframe to other iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a jquery custom scrollbar. My document is made of different iframes. In particular, there're two: one containing a Table Of Contents (toc_iframe) and another one showing the content of the topic selected in the TOC (main_iframe).
The toc_iframe is using a jquery custom scrollbar, applied to an element with id "#content", and I'm trying to get a reference to the scrollbar from the main_iframe in order to call a function of its api.

To do so, I'm using the jquery selector:

```
$("#content",parent.window.frames[0].document)
```

The selector works fine (tested with console.log), but when I call a function of the scrollbar on it, I get the classic error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

```
$("#content",parent.window.frames[0].document).mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",myElt);
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Which iframe is the custom scrollbar plugin loaded in? You're trying to call the function in the main iframe, so the plugin has to be loaded there.

Comment: You can't call functions directly in other iframes. If you want to communicate between iframes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site

Comment: The scrollbar plugin is in the toc_iframe. Basically I have my main.html with the two iframes: toc_iframe and main_iframe. The two iframes load two html files which are in the same directory of main.html

Comment: Each frame is effectively in its own process. You can't call a function loaded in one frame from another, even though you can reference the DOM elements across frames (when they're in the same domain). You need to send a message to the `toc_iframe` telling it what to do, and run a message handler there to respond to it.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree. I've called functions from other iframes before, or at least set variables in them. I'll try to get a working example

Comment: @Barmar Got it working. Here's content of three files you need: main.html: http://pastebin.com/CVPeztcd frame1.html: http://pastebin.com/4DXMfpSs frame2.html: http://pastebin.com/hLT1HJ42 make sure to name the files properly, and you have to have them on a local server, otherwise there'll be a cross-origin error since origins don't work well with local files not being on a server. Then go to the main.html page in browser and wait a few seconds

Comment: @Markasoftware thanks man, it does work! Still having some issue with my scrollbar but I'll figure those out :)
Cheers!

Comment: @Markasoftware Interesting. To extend that to jQuery, it looks like you'd need to do `parent.window.frames[0].jQuery('#content').mCustomScrollbar(...)`, so that you'll run jQuery in the other frame.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, but it might be nicer to do `parent.frames[0].someFunctionName=function(){/*content here*/}` and then run `parent.frames[0].someFunctionName()`, but I'm not sure how that'd work with scoping and stuff

Comment: He's trying to run functions that were already defined in the other frame, because that's where jQuery and the plugin were loaded. So he doesn't need to do that.