# How to close a modal when modal is 3rd party iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a need to launch a third party site as a pop-up iFrame.   When the buttons are selected in the iFrame (Save, Cancel), the iFrame is not closing. I'm using JavaScript to open it (`.modal('show');`), but can't seem to execute a `.modal('hide')` on it.

I was looking up event listeners to see if that was feasible.  However, it appears I need the form id which I currently don't have and I'm not sure the 3rd party can/would provide, or even if that is a viable solution due to security reasons.

Comment: Unless you can get some cooperation from the owner of the third party site this isn't really feasible. See this question for a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site

Comment: Wrap the iFrame in a div or other element of your choice. You will have full control over it, to hide or show or whatever.

Comment: I am wrapping the iFrame in a div, but unable to reference the page object after the Save or Cancel is selected on the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I found out I needed cooperation from the owner of the third party site.  The header tags they were using did not allow for the page to be set as an iFrame.  Once they removed the restriction it began to work.

Comment: Also, instead of closing via java command, we forwarded to a jsp page with AJAX to refresh the 'top' page.