# Difference between custom event and postMessage

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage, custom-events

In order to send a message to another document (let's say an `iframe`), you can use both `postMessage` and `createEvent` functions. Assume this:

```
var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
event.initCustomEvent("message", true, true, 'Hello world');
iframe.dispatchEvent(event);
```

My question is, if both approaches work, what is the difference between using `postMessage` and `customEvent`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's the difference between leaving your neighbour a message asking them to turn down their TV, and trying to break into their apartment to turn down the TV yourself.

You can't dispatch an event into a frame that you are not allowed to access by Same Origin Policy or Access-Control-Allow-Origin, since some of the messages might mess with how that page works. But messages are intended for communication between different pages - if they don't want to listen to the message, they don't have to.

Another difference is that messages must be serialisable, events do not have to be.

Comment: And what if we are in the same domain name?

Comment: Then the results should be similar. Your apartment, your TV. Doesn't matter if you tell your kid to turn it down or do it yourself.

Comment: Awesome. What I was looking for.

Comment: Best example ever

Comment: Well more like throwing a stone at their TV hoping it would stop.

It might or might not stop, but if the host is gracious enough - they would listen to the "request" and turn it down themselves.

Comment: @bendtherules I agree. "... turning down the TV yourself." comes off as if someone can manually modify another page.

Comment: @Luminous Edited. You're still breaking in, but maybe the security is good enough to stop you.