# What are the difference between postMessage() and dispatchEvent() in respect to the origin policy?

Tags: javascript, postmessage, dispatchevent

I have this code, I have set the `MessageEvent` 's origin to `*`, but still the console prompts **Blocked a frame with origin "AAAA" from accessing a frame with origin "BBBB". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.** Anyone know why?

```
  var size = {
    width:  document.body.scrollWidth,
    height:  document.body.scrollHeight
  }
  var evt = new MessageEvent("dimensionMessage",{
      "data": size,
      "origin":"*"
  });
  window.parent.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

However, if I use `window.parent.postMessage(size, "*")` , it works.

Comment: @Kaiido because I want a custom name for the receiver side. This code I placed in the external resource where the iframe `src` is referencing to.

Comment: @Kaiido they are on different domains, that's why I set `origin:"*"` in the first place

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183600/difference-between-custom-event-and-postmessage

Answer (score 6):

The error message tells you that a cross-origin iframe cannot in general invoke a method from the parent if it is in a different origin; that includes the `dispatchEvent` method (otherwise, an iframe could for instance generate mouse events in the parent page).

The `postMessage` API is an exception to that, designed precisely to allow cross-origin communication in a well-defined manner.

(Setting `origin` to '*' won't help you here; in general, that property is expected to be set by the browser when a message is sent via `postMessage`; creating manually a `MessageEvent` object is mostly only useful when you want to simulate in the receiving page the reception of an external message)

Comment: Do note that event while using `"*"`, Cross-Origin Security Policies forbid the operation **if your using the file protocol (`file://`)**, unless you change setting in your browser or OS.

Answer (score 3):

When two documents do not have the same origin, they have very limited access caused by Same-origin policy restrictions.

In your example `dispatchEvent()` has limited access to a different frame (`window.parent`).

`window.postMessage()` allow to perform a cross-window messaging avoiding Same-origin policy restriction.

Parameter `targetOrigin` for `window.postMessage()` specifies what the origin of otherWindow must be for the event to be dispatched, either as the literal string "*" (indicating no preference) or as a URI.

Please note that in your production code you should use a specific URI in order to make your code more secure. More information about how to use `window.postMessage()` securely can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage