# Auto click in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to click automatically button1, which is in iframe which is on my website.
[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldTVd.png)

iframe source:
`...<button class="button1">...`

I can click it automatically using
`document.querySelector('.button1').click();` but only on frame source  page.

My website has `<iframe id="frame1" src="iframe source">`

How to click it automatically from my page?

Comment: I was thinking about this: `document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.querySelector('.button1').click();` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The proper way if through sending a message to the iframe, and on the iframe have an event listener the will fire the click when the message arrives.

here is an [Example on iframe communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="test" source="test.html">

</iframe>
</body>
</html>

In scripts:

$('#test').contents().find('BUTTON ID').click(function(){
alert("works")
});
```

Comment: there is not button id

Comment: you can use class too **find(".button1")**