# Use iframe in Angular 4 app in Single Page Application

Tags: angular, iframe

I have a site which consist of many different html pages, some of them compiled by angular 1, some of them use jQuery, some not. But now, I need to make one spa of this pages.

I have very many modals and tables, so how can I do it by pieces?

I prefer to use iframe tag. How can I realize 2-ways event bindings? For example, if I click a button(show modal) inside iframe page, modal must open from the parent page.

Or maybe there is the best solution to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: it will be angular 4 app

Comment: I do not think that you will be able to find any high level event abstraction layer here. What are you looking for is HTML5 Web Messaging specification. Here is good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site P.S. Your project seems to be nightmare. I'd recommend changing workplace ;)

Comment: I agree with you about this project, but i wanna do it)) Thank you, Arek:)