# Is it possible to access an external web page (not mine) using iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe

I want to make a chrome extension which loads an iframe of a different website onto the background page, and interacts with it using JS/jQuery.

Specifically, I want it to search for something on this website (on a different domain) and return the URL of the first result.

I've read about Same-origin policy so I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this, but does anyone have a workaround? Or a different method entirely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe#comment2590499_364952) comment sums it up pretty nicely. The browser prohibits it for a purpose. A proxy is probably your only option.