# fill iframe input field from click on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

I have an iframe containing a form. On the parent page, I have an interactive div which populates data on mouse clicks (map.)
Is there a way where I can fill an input field that is part of the iframe by clicking on something from the parent page?

Comment: Do you have access to the iframe code? Can you add some Javascript to it?

Comment: @SergiiVorobei yes I do. It’s a form with fields where user inputs some data then clicks upload to upload the file to the server

Comment: Please take a look at this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate between your page and iFrame content using messages.

```
// frame.html:
window.onmessage = function(event) {
    // handle message and fill input field
    var text = event.data;
};

// page:
// <iframe id="myframe" src="framed.htm"></iframe>

document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.postMessage('textToFill','*');
```