# How to call or trigger Angular component method from javascript (.js file) button click event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to trigger an angular component method when i click on an html button which is located inside a separate plain HTML file in the 'src' folder in the same project.

I tried different ways through NgZone, callback function, etc but the angular component method is not firing.

Comment: What connection does a _separate plain HTML file in the 'src' folder_ have to Angular? How is it included in your SPA?

Answer (score 0):

simple custom event seems to be helpful

```
//   in component  
document.addEventListener('myEvent',()=>{
  console.log('here it is')
});

// in js file
var event = new Event('myEvent');
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the way you suggested. But somehow am not seeing the event getting triggered when i click on button click in html file.
I have included the below code in button click event of the html file

var event = new Event('myEvent');
document.dispatchEvent(event);


Then I have included the below code in the constructor and nginit() of the xxxxx.component.ts file

document.addEventListener('myEvent',()=>{
  console.log('here it is')
});
But still I see the event is not getting triggered when button click in html file.
Plz let me know if m missing anything

Comment: Please find the Stackblitz link below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ggxxv
I have created stand alone editor.html under "src" folder which has html button for triggering angular method. In app.component.ts, I have included the eventListener in ngOnInit() method. In angular.json, I have included the stand alone file editor.html for running it independently

Comment: editor.html is another html page, you want it to communicate with index.html when open in two different tabs?

Comment: No, I want to communicate from "editor.html" to "app.component.ts". In "editor.html", I would be having button and iframe control. In Iframe src, i would be loading "app.component". Therefore during button (which is available in editor.html) click, I want to invoke a method defined in "app.component.ts"

Comment: here is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site. Use postmessage instead of events

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an component named c1 and for this component you have an html file associated to it.

[image]

So, in your html file you need to add a button like that:

```
<button (click)="clickMe()"></button>
```

In your typescript file implement your method:

```
clickMe() { //your code here }
```

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is referring to a component template file due to: _a separate plain HTML file in the 'src' folder_

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes I agree with you, because there is no sense to create a new html file separated and execute a typescript code inside, we more clarifications

Comment: @Amine, We had this requirement to execute an angular component method from an external html/javascript file. Here HTML file is not the one which is available as part of the component. It is a separate stand alone file located in src folder of the same project

Answer (score 0):

In your js file, throw event like below:

```
window.postMessage("Disconnected", "*")
```

And In your ts file, you can listen to that event like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  window.onmessage = (e)=>{
    if (e.data == 'Disconnected') {
      alert("Yeah! it's working");
      //you can call any method here
    }
  };
}
```