# Using postMessage to send short string value to the iFrame

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page with an iFrame inside and I want to send short string value from parent to the iFrame.  The short string value is a file name like "voice2.mp3" and the iFrame uses **WaveSurfer** to play the audio file.

So far I check if the string value has changed using intervals on the iFrame side  and, yes it works fine.

**But I'm wondering how can I do this using postMessage and I have no idea how to implement it in my code?**

Here is the iFrame code:

```
window.nameOld = "voice1.mp3";

setInterval(function(){ 
var name = parent.window.postMe;

if(name !== window.nameOld){
       console.log("name Changed");

       window.nameOld = name;
       wavesurfer.load(name);
       runFunc();
};


}, 1000);

var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: '#edeaef',
    progressColor: '#d3cbd8',
    cursorColor: '#9800ff',
    cursorWidth: 1,
    interact: false,
    responsive: true,
    hideScrollbar: true,
});


    function runFunc(){
    wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play();
});
    wavesurfer.on('finish', function () {
    console.log("Just finished!");
    wavesurfer.pause();
});

    }
```

And here is the parent code which will be executed on button click:

```
window.postMe= "voice2.mp3";
```

Comment: I would suggest starting with [some good documentation on postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Note that that documentation includes [information on how to receive the posted message in the iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#The_dispatched_event) as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Answer (score 1):

I might not be fully understanding this but correct me if I'm wrong, you are wanting to know how to send a message as a parent to a child IFrame? If so, you would want to include JQuery and use JQuery.postMessage from the parent side and JQuery.recieveMessage from the child IFrame. That should remove the code running on interval.

Comment: I think jQuery has nothing to do with the question. He is referring to Window.postMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Yes you are right, I completely forgot about that. JQuery has postMessage and recieveMessage methods that I used to create my previous project.

Comment: wait a minute... I can get rid of intervals using jQuery... that's smart thank you... plus one

Comment: But I need more help on this...Where should I start from?

Comment: I suggest you maybe start from looking at examples (like this one http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/).