# is possible Blazor Server Side App embedded in other website(e.g wordpress) without using iframe

Tags: iframe, blazor-server-side

I have an **Blazor Server side(SingnalR version)** app, which is deployed to the azure web app service. Each page component has its own URL e.g.(https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/pageX)

The plan was to embed the Blazor server app into a Wordpress apps. The Wordpress developer asked me whether i can offer a HTML-Snippet instead of URL. With URL he can only set the URL into an IFrame. he stated it is really bad for SEO.

Is it really possible for each page component of a Blazor Server app, to create a corresponding HTML snippet? or just do not work in that way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can render the HTML in that way from Blazor. You could host the SEO component in Blazor so it sends the data to SEO service for each page rendered.

If only the WordPress site can access the SEO, you might look communicating the page changes from the iframe and the parent using messages:

[How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)