# JavaScript: how override window.close and window.open of iframe (same origin)?

Tags: javascript

I want override iframe `window.close` and `window.open`, I have tried in parent window

```
const winIframe = document.querySelectorAll('IFRAME')[0].contentWindow;

// override window.close
winIframe.close = () => {
    alert('close ');
};

// override window.open
winIframe.open = () => {
    alert('open');
};
```

nothing happen...

how override window.close and window.open of iframe (same origin)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site and handle onload nad onbeforeunload in iframe then send message to parent