# Writing to textbox inside iFrame on Wix website

Tags: iframe, velo, log4js-node

I have a Wix website and I'm simply trying to write to a textbox inside an iFrame. It seems like a straightforward thing, but I can't find and code examples. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: First https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154267/863110. Is it an iframe component or external iframe? Does this site has domain (If it does, you can inject script which make it easier)

Comment: It's asimple iFrame in a Wix website page. The above example uses the Windows framework syntax which unfortunately has no correspondence to the NodeJS syntax. I figured out how to insert a textbox inside an iFrame, but for the life of me I haven't figured out how to add text to it from outside the iFrame.