# Best way to interact with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-devtools

Hey guys i really need your help. I am creating some kind of application for dynamically searching multiple items. For example, I want to search specific products in one store via iframe(for example, src will be 'www.store.com/search'), i create a array of all objects which i want to search and i create loop which will change iframe's src('www.store.com/search/item-1', 'www.store.com/search/item-2', etc.). I need to access price for selected item, preferably through iframes dom element. I was trying to access iframes dom element and console with no success (Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame). I am pretty sure im not headed in the right direction, does anyone have better solution or a way to bypass this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't control the contents inside of the iframe there is no easy way to do this. The web browser has a security feature (called CORS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to prevent this sort of interaction for security reasons.

In order for this to be possible the page inside of the iframe needs to be your page, and you need to configure the CORS settings on it to allow being used with an iframe like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).