# iframe to display 3 pages in a single page

Tags: html, css

I am displaying 3 iframes in a single page, I want to make my page such that if click a button in the 1st iframe the page changes in the 2nd iframe, and if I click the button in 2nd iframe the page changes in the 3rd iframe and vice-versa. Can anybody help me to accomplish it or give a hint how to do so? As of now I have created a separated page for which have iframe code for all the 3 frames. Below is the example

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8QFV.png)

Comment: Are all websites under the same domain?

Comment: I am trying to make resume/portfolio website, it isn't hosted yet

Comment: Anyways, this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site

Answer (score 0):

Well this can only be achieved using JavaScript. In this case I assume you are using plain HTML,CSS and vanilla JavaScript, DOM manipulation is the best way to do so.
For better understanding you can share the code. Thankyou.

Comment: yup, i am using plain HTML, CSS, isn't there any easy way to do so, here is link to my website code (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zFHYewaa8MdVgQQO5vS_703uKITbqqSr?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well its not that difficult but you need  JavaScript. I saw your code. using JavaScript you can to change the value"src" attribute in the iframe tag to your desired page (e.g page.html) by making a click event on any item in another iframe.

Comment: As of now I am not certain about what exactly you want things to happen in your website but from what I understand using javaScript is only way in my opinion.