# Is it possible to detect if a POST request was initiated inside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, angular, post, iframe, http-post

I have an angular application which renders an iframe and at a certain point in time, a POST request will be initiated inside this iframe automatically. Is it possible to detect when this POST request was initiated or even detect the successful or unsuccessful completion of the POST request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site