# JQuery trigger function after post request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe on my website wherein user can do a POST request by clicking submit on a button. In the parent page wherein this iframe is located, I would like to have a function triggering when the POST request is sent to the server (or ideally when the response for the POST request is received). After the POST request is sent, the page in the iframe reloads; so it's also fine to trigger the function on the reload of the iframe.

Is wither of this possible with JQuery (or another JavaScript Library)?

Comment: wither --> either

Comment: Maybe this post will be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9153445/3397771