# How to style the body of an empty iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I got this problem only on IE (even on most recent versions, like 11). The thing is that I appended an iframe dinamicly to my document in which I'm writing some scripts for later execution. Those scripts must paint an image in the end, the problem is I'm getting anoying margins on IE from the body.

I can't load that using the src, it must be dynamic. So I just thought "lets get access to the iframe and write some style on the body". But when I retrieve the iframe doc like this...

```
var win = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
```

... `win.document.body` or `win.document.querySelector("body")` returns null (again, in ie 11).

**Does anyone know how to get to the body safely?**

Comment: put a style sheet that targets the body inside the iframe itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could write some css like this:

```
win.document.open();
win.document.write("<style>body{margin:0;}</style>");
//write other stuff
win.document.close();
```

This works as doesn't avoid any further writting and also because style can be in the head or in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="" id="iframe"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
   iframe.setAttribute("srcdoc", "<style>body{background:red;}</style>");
</script>
```

Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/kaquwilaka

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if you write something on the iframe

Comment: This will override the internal content of Iframe.

Comment: You can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328679/how-to-pass-a-value-from-iframe-to-the-parent/32329724#32329724 . Send message to Iframe to change color.

Comment: the iframe is empty, how is sending messages to it suppose to help me?

Comment: If the iframe is empty then you can use the above method.

Comment: It is empty when I create it, of course! There is no sense on writing scripts that read messages...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88469/discussion-between-anand-sudhanaboina-and-vandervals).